# Login does not redirect to dashboard, rather it returns same login page

Tags: python, django

I have defined a view that redirect logged in users to their dashboard, but when I enter the login details on the login form, it just reloads and display the same login page but with empty field instead of redirecting to the dashboard.

My views.py:

```
def doctor_login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DoctorLoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
            print(user)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('doctor_dashboard')  # Redirect to the doctors' dashboard
            else:
                form.add_error(None, 'Invalid email or password.')

    else:
        form = DoctorLoginForm()

    return render(request, 'doctor_login.html', {'form': form})
```

My forms.py:

```
class DoctorLoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=255)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

My urls.py:

```
path('doctor/login/', views.doctor_login_view, name='doctor_login'),
```

Login Template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Doctor Login</h2>
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'doctor_login' %}">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <!-- Login form fields -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" required>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    </form>
    <p class="mt-3">Don't have an account? <a href="{% url 'doctor_registration' %}" class="btn btn-link">Register</a></p>
  </div>

  {% endblock %}
```

I have tried to check if the url path is correct and the post method for the form is correctly renderes in the login template. It seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please give full code of urls.py,

please confirm that 'doctor_dashboard' path exists.

For example add url like this

```
path('doctor/login/', views.doctor_login_view, name='doctor_login'),
path('doctor/dashboard/', views.doctor_dashboard_view, name='doctor_dashboard'),
```

Also not to forget create a new function for doctor_dashboard_view

```
def doctor_login_view(request):
       ....
```